# Office 365 installation failed with Error 12007-4?

Tags: office365

I try to install Office 365 Pro Plus .
But it failed with Error 12007-4 at the installation begin ?
Have any Idea to fix it Please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to set web Proxy ?
Try to run this command :

```
bitsadmin /util /setieproxy localsystem MANUAL_PROXY proxyserver:port NULL
```

and Try to turn Off you're anti-virus and firewall .
this Error related to web-Proxy and you're anti-virus and firewall .

Comment: after I run this command and turn off firewall (don't have anti-virus ) now Setup able running but goes to Error in 17% for two times ?

Comment: after you do what I said above you need to restart you're system and run again , Remember :  you must remove all other version of office first .....